# Generic data constructor from Maybe arguments

Tags: haskell

I have a bunch of data structures like `data Foo = Foo {a :: Type1, b :: Type2} deriving (Something)` with `Type1` and `Type2` being always different (generally primitive types but it's irrelevant) and in different numbers.

I came to have a bunch of functions like

```
justFooify :: Maybe Type1 -> Maybe Type2 -> Maybe Foo
justFooify f b =
  | isNothing f = Nothing
  | isNothing b = Nothing
  | otherwise   = Just $ Foo (fromJust f) (fromJust b)
```

Is there something I'm missing? After the third such function I wrote I came to think that *maybe* it could be too much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need applicatives!

```
import Control.Applicative

justFooify :: Maybe Type1 -> Maybe Type2 -> Maybe Foo
justFooify f b = Foo <$> f <*> b
```

Or you can use `liftA2` in this example:

```
justFooify = liftA2 Foo
```

It acts like `liftM2`, but for `Applicative`.  If you have more parameters, just use more `<*>`s:

```
data Test = Test String Int Double String deriving (Eq, Show)

buildTest :: Maybe String -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Double -> Maybe String -> Maybe Test
buildTest s1 i d s2 = Test <$> s1 <*> i <*> d <*> s2
```

---

What are `Applicative`s?  They're basically a more powerful `Functor` and a less powerful `Monad`, they fall right in between.  The definition of the typeclass is

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
    pure :: a -> f a
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    -- plus a few more things that aren't important right now
```

If your `Applicative` is also a `Monad`, then `pure` is the same as `return` (in fact, some people feel that having `return` is incorrect, we should only have `pure`).  The `<*>` operator is what makes them more powerful than `Functor`s, though.  It gives you a way to put a function in your data structure, then apply that function to values also wrapped in your data structure.  So when you have something like

```
> :t Test    -- Our construct
Test :: String -> Int -> Double -> String -> Test
> :t fmap Test    -- also (Test <$>), since (<$>) = fmap
fmap Test :: Functor f => f String -> f (Int -> Double -> String -> Test)
```

We see that it constructs a function inside of a `Functor`, since `Test` takes multiple arguments.  So `Test <$> Just "a"` has the type `Maybe (Int -> Double -> String -> Test)`.  With just `Functor` and `fmap`, we can't apply anything to the inside of that `Maybe`, but with `<*>` we can.  Each application of `<*>` applies one argument to that inner `Functor`, which should now be considered an `Applicative`.

Another handy thing about it is that it works with *all* Monads (that currently define their `Applicative` instance).  This means lists, `IO`, functions of one argument, `Either e`, parsers, and more.  For example, if you were getting input from the user to build a `Test`:

```
askString :: IO String
askInt :: IO Int
askDouble :: IO Double
-- whatever you might put here to prompt for it, or maybe it's read from disk, etc

askForTest :: IO Test
askForTest = Test <$> askString <*> askInt <*> askDouble <*> askString
```

And it'd still work.  This is the power of Applicatives.

---

FYI, in GHC 7.10 there will be implemented the [Functor-Applicative-Monad Proposal](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal).  This will change the definition of `Monad` from

```
class Monad m where
    return :: a -> m a
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

to

```
class Applicative m => Monad m where
    return :: a -> m a
    return = pure
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
    join :: m (m a) -> m a
```

(more or less).  This will break some old code, but many people are excited for it as it will mean that all Monads are Applicatives and all Applicatives are Functors, and we'll have the full power of these algebraic objects at our disposal.

Comment: @marco Check my edits, it might help explain `Applicative`s a bit more so that you can understand what's going on.